# How to use event listeners in symfony2 with annotations

Tags: php, symfony

i am new to symfony2 and i am learning to use event listerners.

I have this code

```
/** @Entity @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
class User
{
    // ...

/** @ORM\PrePersist */

    public function setPassword()
    {


        $this->password = "EVENTS";
    }
```

Now do i need anything else as well to make this code work. i mean what else do i need to do for this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HasLifecycleCallbacks =  to notify Doctrine that this entity has entity life-cycle callback annotations set on at least one of its methods

Possible annotations on the methods

@PostLoad, @PrePersist, @PostPersist, @PreRemove, @PostRemove, @PreUpdate or @PostUpdate

So, your code is good enough.